# Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework.Element is obsolete - What is the replacement

Tags: xdb, xconnect, experience-analytics

In Sitecore 9.3 Sitecore analytics, if I try and inherit Element, I see an obsolete message:

> Assembly Sitecore.Analytics.Model, Version=14.0.0.0

```
[Obsolete("Will be removed in the next version.")]
public abstract class Element : IElement, IValidatable
{
    protected Element();

    public bool IsEmpty { get; }
    protected IModelMemberCollection Members { get; }

    protected void EnsureAttribute<TValue>(string name);
    protected void EnsureCollection<TElement>(string name) where TElement : class, IElement;
    protected void EnsureDictionary<TElement>(string name) where TElement : class, IElement;
    protected void EnsureElement<TElement>(string name) where TElement : class, IElement;
    protected TValue GetAttribute<TValue>(string name);
    protected IElementCollection<TElement> GetCollection<TElement>(string name) where TElement : class, IElement;
    protected IElementDictionary<TElement> GetDictionary<TElement>(string name) where TElement : class, IElement;
    protected TElement GetElement<TElement>(string name) where TElement : class, IElement;
    protected virtual void OnValidate();
    protected void SetAttribute<TValue>(string name, TValue value);
}
```

What is the replacement of `GetElement<TElement>`, `SetAttribute<TValue>` and `GetCollection<TElement>` in Sitecore 9.3 xConnect.

Is there an example somewhere. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 4):

You would need to rewrite your code to not inherit from Element as it is removed in later versions. You can also take a look at the implementation in 10.1 for the models in the namespace `Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Generated`.

The methods `EnsureAttribute, EnsureDictionary, EnsureElement` were used in the constructor as a check to add the object to the collection if it didn't exist, but in the newer versions these aren't used anymore.

```
public ContactPhoneNumbers()
{
   this.EnsureAttribute<string>(nameof (Preferred));
   this.EnsureDictionary<IPhoneNumber>(nameof (Entries));
}

public ContactPhoneNumbers()
{
}
```

Instead of `SetAttribute` and `GetAttribute` you would need to read the values from the Fields collection, for example:

```
public string Country
    {
      get => this.GetAttribute<string>(nameof (Country));
      set => this.SetAttribute<string>(nameof (Country), value);
    }

Address.Fields uint16 = (Address.Fields) info.GetUInt16("f");
if (uint16.HasFlag((Enum) Address.Fields.Country))
  this.Country = info.GetString("c");

public string Country { get; set; }
```

The same would be for `GetCollection`:

```
public IElementCollection<ITagValue> Values => this.GetCollection<ITagValue>(nameof (Values));

[Obsolete("Deprecated in 10.0.0. Use Entries instead.")]
public IElementCollection<ITagValue> Values => (IElementCollection<ITagValue>) new ElementCollection<ITagValue>(this.Entries);

public IList<ITagValue> Entries => this._entries ?? (this._entries = (IList<ITagValue>) new List<ITagValue>());
```